# C++ Program is giving wrong output

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve a simple problem using C++. The problem statement is this :

N triangles are given. And Each triangle is identified by the coordinates of its three corners in the 2-D cartesian plane. The job is to figure out how many of the given triangles are right triangles. A right triangle is a triangle in which one angle is a 90 degree angle. The vertices of the triangles have integer coordinates and all the triangles given are valid( three points aren't colinear ).

Input : The first line of the input contains an integer N denoting the number of triangles. Each of the following N lines contain six space separated integers x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 where (x1, y1), (x2, y2) and (x3, y3) are the vertices of a triangle.

Output : Output one integer, the number of right triangles among the given triangles.

My C++ Program is this :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;

    cout<<"\n";

    int ans = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3;
        cin>>x1>>y1>>x2>>y2>>x3>>y3;

        double side1 = (double)sqrt( ( (x1-x2) * (x1-x2) ) + ( (y1-y2) * (y1-y2) ) );
        double side2 = (double)sqrt( ( (x2-x3) * (x2-x3) ) + ( (y2-y3) * (y2-y3) ) );
        double side3 = (double)sqrt( ( (x1-x3) * (x1-x3) ) + ( (y1-y3) * (y1-y3) ) );

        double A = side1 * side1;
        double B = side2 * side2;
        double C = side3 * side3;

        cout<<"A = "<<A<<"  B = "<<B<<"  C = "<<C<<"\n";

        cout<<"A+B = "<<A+B<<" , ";
        cout<<"B+C = "<<B+C<<" , ";
        cout<<"A+C = "<<A+C;

        cout<<"\n";

        if( (A + B) == C )
        {
            ans++;
            cout<<"first\n";
        }
        else if( (B + C) == A )
        {
            ans++;
            cout<<"second\n";
        }
        else if( (A + C) == B )
        {
            ans++;
            cout<<"third\n";
        }

        cout<<"\n\n";
    }

    cout<<"ans = "<<ans;

}
```

Output of above program is this :

[image]

**But the Correct Output should be ans = 3 , because the first triangle and the last two triangles of the input example are right triangles.**

I am not getting why my program is giving wrong output.

Comment: After using if() instead of using elseif() also, it is giving me same wrong output.

Comment: @SAPJV Try adding `std::cout << std::setprecision(1000);` at the top of `main`. You'll see some interesting results.

Comment: I strongly recommend to separate the test of one triangle, into a functions perhaps, and the input/output code

Comment: I think it might be because of the precision, so I would vote for @HolyBlackCat solution (or rather comment)

Comment: Rewrite the code without floating-point types (without `double`, and without `sqrt`).

Comment: Try https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZWUEnie4kkDnlHx4

Comment: would pow() will work fine here ?

Comment: @SAPJV I wouldn't rely on it. Are you thinking about replacing `sqrt` with it? You don't need to take square roots at all here, since you immediately square those roots.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I got your points and suggestions, Thanks for that. Now, the problem has been resolved. setprecision() helped a lot.

Answer (score -2):

In this piece of code:

```
        if( (A + B) == C )
        {
            ans++;
            cout<<"first\n";
        }
        else if( (B + C) == A )
        {
            ans++;
            cout<<"second\n";
        }
        else if( (A + C) == B )
        {
            ans++;
            cout<<"third\n";
        }
```

your program only enters *one* code block, the first one whose condition is `true`. Since you put `else if`, the block after it will only be entered if the `else if` condition is `true`,  **and** the previous condition was *false*.

Thus, you never increment `ans` by more than 1.

To solve this, you could do either:

```
        if( (A + B) == C )
        {
            ans++;
            cout<<"first\n";
        }

        if( (B + C) == A )
        {
            ans++;
            cout<<"second\n";
        }

        if( (A + C) == B )
        {
            ans++;
            cout<<"third\n";
        }
```

which will only work if more than 1 condition can be true at a time, or this:

```
        if( (A + B) == C )
        {
            ans = 1;
            cout<<"first\n";
        }
        else if( (B + C) == A )
        {
            ans = 2;
            cout<<"second\n";
        }
        else if( (A + C) == B )
        {
            ans = 3;
            cout<<"third\n";
        }
```

Comment: The whole `if/else` block is in `for` loop.

Comment: No, It is still not working. I have already tried this.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Oh indeed you're right. In this case my answer is crap :)